# Extract foreground from background in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have 2 images. One is background image and other image has same background but with some foreground object. I want to extract foreground object from background. Simple subtraction operation in matlab will not suffice as it subtracts RGB value of background image from that of foreground image (as in below code).

```
im1 = imread('output/frame-1.jpg')
im2 = imread('output/frame-7.jpg')

%# subtract
deltaImage = im1 - im2;
imshow(deltaImage)
```

So if background color is **white** and foreground object is **blue**, then output (i.e. deltaImage) comes foreground object with **orange** color with **black** background. However the output I want is foreground object with ***blue*** color (i.e. original color) with ***black*** background. How can I get this ? I tried to do it using below code, but output image is incorrect.

```
im1 = imread('foreground.jpg')
im2 = imread('background.jpg')
[m n k]=size(im2);
deltaImage = zeros(m,n,3);
fprintf('%d %d %d.\n',m,n,k);
for l=1:k
    for i=1:m-1
        for j=1:n-1
           if  im1(i:j:l)~=im2(i:j:l)
               deltaImage(i,j,l) = im1(i,j,l);
           end
        end 
    end
end
imshow(deltaImage)
```

1. Background IMAGE

[image]

2. Foreground Image

[image]

3. Output Image **(Here I want color of man to be blue)**

[image]

Comment: Only subtract the background image if the pixels are equal?

Comment: @hari_OM So, do you like my answer or not? Any questions? Comments?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `deltaImage` to create a mask (zeros and ones image) that multiplies the foreground. However, note that you will have artifacts associated with lossy image compression (`.jpeg`). These can be reduced, *to some extent*, if you use a threshold, like the average difference or a specific value you want. Try this:

```
im1 = double(imread('~/Downloads/foreground.jpg'));
im2 = double(imread('~/Downloads/background.jpg'));
```

compute the difference of the averages of the 3 channels

```
deltaImage = mean(im2,3) - mean(im1,3);
```

then use the product of the mean by a standard deviation (`~3`), **or** uncomment the line below to use a specific threshold, like `128`

```
mask = deltaImage>3*mean(deltaImage(:));  
% mask = deltaImage>128;
```

then assuming all original images are in 8-bit format produce a result also in 8-bit format:

```
result = uint8(cat(3, im1(:,:,1).*mask, im1(:,:,2).*mask, im1(:,:,3).*mask));
imshow(result)
```

And this is the result you should get:

[image: output]

*Again* the weird looking pixels around the main object are artifacts of lossy image compression (`.jpeg`), you should try working with lossless like `.png` formats.

Comment: I was getting error as **Error using .* Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.**. So I made this change: `result = double(im1).*mask;` 
After running the code I am getting output like this: [work4hari.net78.net/stackoverflow/output1.jpg ](http://work4hari.net78.net/stackoverflow/output1.jpg)

Comment: @hari_OM The result is odd, there are lots of artifacts caused by poor compression. I have edited the answer, hopefully you will accept it.

Comment: I used your method and got output similar to what you have shown. However I tried your method over `.png` format, but still I am getting noise in output. One more question that arises is that when we do `deltaImage = im1 - im2;`, their is no noise in output.